# outlook addin not installing for 2010 and 2013

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, add-in

Hi I have an outlook com addin that is working fine with outlook 2000, 2003 and 2007 but not even installing for 2010 and 2013. In outlook 2000, 2003 and 2007 it is showing mscoree.dll as addin location.

how to make it work for 2010 and 2013

Comment: Check out Outlook Options --> Add-Ins --> Manage: [Disabled Items] --> click [Go]. Does your add-in listed there?

Comment: I already did this but it is not showing anywhere in outlook add-ins i.e., not in disabled, active or inactive